# require "d3-select-multi" as node module not working

Tags: node.js, d3.js, npm, module

I installed d3 via npm and require it in my script directly (for some reason)

So:

`npm install d3`

and then

`var d3 = require("d3");`

works fine.

The problem is now, that I need the "d3-selection-multi"-module.

I installed it also via npm

`npm install d3-selection-multi`

In the d3-Doku I read you could require different modules like so:

`var d3 = Object.assign({}, require("d3-format"), require("d3-geo"), require("d3-geo-projection"));`

I changed that to my needs which would be to have the standard-d3-bundle (that worked already above) and add the d3-selection-multi.

`var d3 = Object.assign({}, require("d3"), require("d3-selection-multi"));`

That does not work however. 
So I tested it by printing out the resulting object:

`console.log(d3)`

The result is correctly:

`{version: "4.11.0", bisect: ƒ, bisectRight: ƒ, bisectLeft: ƒ, ascending: ƒ, …}`

But the "d3-selection-multi"-module is not there. I can see that, because it doesn't recognize `d3.selectAll().styles` as a function.

I tried the following:
instead of

`var d3 = Object.assign({}, require("d3"), require("d3-selection-multi"));`

I just required the d3-selection-multi to see whether it works:

`var d3 = require("d3-selection-multi");`

and the result of `console.log(d3)` is
`{ }` An empty object.

So if this object does not contain anything the `Object.assign` obviously also doesn't add anything to the d3-standard-bundle. But why is it empty? Am I missing sth?

Comment: Have a look at [*"How to install d3-selection-multi from Node (CommonJS)"*](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi/issues/9).

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it's a little difficult to determine exactly what you're encountering that's convinced you this isn't working, so I'm working on a guess that it's this:

> But the "d3-selection-multi"-module is not there. I can see that, because it doesn't recognize d3.selectAll().styles as a function.

Let's start from the beginning.

[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) copies enumerable properties of one or more source objects to a single target object.  This is useful for creating shallow copies of objects--for example, allowing you to manipulate the target object without necessarily manipulating the source object--or to compose a new object with properties from the source objects.

```
const foo = { a: 1 };
const bar = { b: 2 };
const baz = Object.assign({}, foo, bar);

console.log(baz.a);
// 1
```

`d3-selection-multi` exports an empty object, as you observed.  Thus, your attempt to use `Object.assign` resulted in the creation of an empty object, the copying of `d3` enumerable properties to that empty object, and the copying of the empty `d3-selection-multi` object's enumerable properties--nothing--to that initial empty object.

[What `d3-selection-multi` does](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi/blob/master/index.js), in fact, is modify the `selection` and `transition` prototypes from `d3-selection` and `d3-transition` directly.

You should be able to verify this by the following trivial example:

```
const d3 = require('d3');
require('d3-selection-multi');

console.log(d3.selectAll().styles);
console.log(d3.selectAll().attrs);
// [Function: selection_styles]
// [Function: selection_attrs]
```

That stated, you *should* see the same result given your original method as well:

```
const d3 = Object.assign({}, require('d3'), require('d3-selection-multi'));
```

If you are indeed able to access `d3.selectAll().styles` and `attrs` this way but still having problems, we'll need to see the exact implementing code along with console output.

Comment: `const d3 = require('d3');

require('d3-selection-multi');

console.log(d3.selectAll().styles);

console.log(d3.selectAll().attrs);`


Both return undefined if I require as above.

I also tried:

`import * as d3 from "d3";

import "d3-selection-multi";`

Same result.

d3 is there either way (so the require or import works), but not the "d3-selection-multi"-module

Comment: Can you attach your actual code?  I tested the above while I was writing my answer and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: It's inside the link function of a Angular-directive. So the first lines are just to set that up.

Comment: `import{ app } from "./app";

angular.module('myModule').directive('scatterplot', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      thisdata: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'templates/scatterplot.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

      const d3 = require("d3");
      require('d3-selection-multi');
     
      console.log(d3.selectAll().styles);
      console.log(d3.selectAll().attrs);
}`

Comment: In the future, better to attach code to the question itself rather than in a comment.  That said, if this is for the browser, why not import `d3` and `d3-selection-multi` using simple `<script>` tags?  See http://briantford.com/blog/angular-d3

Comment: I found out what was the problem in my case. I used an old version of node (4.4.4).
I used `nvm use 6.2.2`, removed d3 and all d3-packages and reinstalled them using the newer node and it worked.

Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks a lot for helping. Your answer helped me by assuring me that it had to be sth else! Thx.